# Bokeh: Making charts "interact" or link with one another

Tags: python, bokeh

To better explain what I mean in the title...

Let's say I have line plot graph that shows adjusted close for a stock for 01.01.2016 until now, and then i have another bokeh chart that displays histogram of volumes for the exact same stock for exact same time period. 
What I want is:

1. Zoom in on a particular time period in adj close graph
2. Have volume histogram graph adjust to the same time period.
3. and vice versa...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seem to me that [this example](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/blob/master/examples/app/ohlc/main.py) do something very similar to what you are you asking for.

The bit that link one chart to another is in figure definition, i.e in:

`p2 = figure(x_range=p.x_range)`

`x_range=p.x_range` link the x range of the current figure with x range of figure `p`.